# Rails - format Time in API response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

i have a model places in relationship with the model opening_times.

In my places_controller i have this:

```
def index
  places = Place.all

  if places
    render json: {
      status: :ok,
      result: places.as_json(
        only: [
          :id,
          :name,
        ],
        include: [
          { opening_times: {only: [:dayWeek, :open, :close]}},
        ]
      )
    }
  else
    render json: { errors: 'invalid request' }, status: 422
  end
end

private
  def place_params
    params.require(:place).permit(:user_id, :name)
  end
```

The open and close columns in DB are `time`.

How can i force to return a format time as `%H:%M`?

Comment: please add whole of Your places_controller

Comment: @num8er i have updated...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not developing on RoR 3+ years... fill free to fix if there is any problem

So can You try this:

```
places = Place.all.map {|place| 
  place.opening_times.map! {|opening_time|
    opening_time[:open].strftime! "%H:%M"
    opening_time[:close].strftime! "%H:%M"
  }
}
```